# Get the total column fields of a table in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can i get the total column fields from a result array in the controller function?.

> I get that by using like `$fields  = $query->list_fields()` on `model` but how can i get it from `controller`.

## Controller function:

```
$result = $this->admin_model->national_certificate_user_search_print($start_date, $end_date);
$total = sizeof($result);  // getting total rows
```

## Model function:

```
public function national_certificate_user_search_print($start_date, $end_date) {
        $tablename = 'national_certificate';
        $query = $this->db->select('user_name,gurdiant_name,mother_name,prm_village_name,prm_post_office,prm_thana,prm_district,prsnt_address,prsnt_ward,prsnt_post_office,prsnt_thana,prsnt_district')
                         ->from($tablename)
                         ->where( "uploaded_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ", NULL, FALSE )
                         ->get(); 
       $result = $query->result_array();
    //   var_dump($query->num_fields()); 
       return $result; 
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not a standard to fetch data in controller directly. You should call a model function. That is what for `MVC`.

Comment: Is that i need to call another function to get the column fields?

Comment: just return the `$query` object from model instead of result_array()

Comment: how can i get the total rows and total column fields number after i return $query from the controller $result ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

## Controller:

```
$result = $this->admin_model->national_certificate_user_search_print($start_date, $end_date);
$total = $result->list_fields();  //this will work now with Object
```

## Model:

```
public function national_certificate_user_search_print($start_date, $end_date) {
        $tablename = 'national_certificate';
        $query = $this->db->select('user_name,gurdiant_name,mother_name,prm_village_name,prm_post_office,prm_thana,prm_district,prsnt_address,prsnt_ward,prsnt_post_office,prsnt_thana,prsnt_district')
                         ->from($tablename)
                         ->where( "uploaded_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ", NULL, FALSE )
                         ->get(); 
       return $query; 
    }
}
```

Here you just need to return `$query` Object from `Model` and then you can use it in `Controller` so that `list_fields()` function working in `controller`.